# why is a backup partition mounted instead of the one designated in fstab

Tags: fstab, disk, automount

I have disks `/dev/sda` & `/dev/sdb`. The `/dev/sdb` is my internal backup drive.

The partitions on `sdb` were set up by dd-ing the corresponding `sda` partitions, so I presume that is why `blkid` shows the UUIDs on `sdb` are the same as the corresponding partitions on `sda`.

Though fstab says

```
/dev/sda3  /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

mount says

```
/dev/sdb3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

This situation leaves me with no backup.

What to do?

......................................

@oldfred - Thank you for your help. However... I did 
    tune2fs /dev/sda3 -U `uuid`... 
for all the /dev/sd* partitions, edited fstab to use 
the UUIDs (from blkid), rebooted, & still have the 
sdb3 backup of sda3 mounted after reboot.

```
[root:/home/rbf]# blkid | egrep -e 'sd.3'
/dev/sda3: UUID="c8c5991e-44f4-11e8-9876-4061864bb8d0" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000d55c4-03"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="861f07b1-621f-459d-bdf1-0b4ef334b0f5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000d55c4-03"

[root:/home/rbf]# grep c8c5991e-44f4-11e8-9876-4061864bb8d0 /etc/fstab #sda3
UUID=c8c5991e-44f4-11e8-9876-4061864bb8d0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

[root:/home/rbf]# mount | egrep -e '/dev/sd.3'
/dev/sdb3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

On backup tools, I currently use the venerable cp command to back up,
because it's old & I understand it (like myself).

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
cp -pdfuR /boot/* /mnt/sdb1
```

etc. Do you see a problem with this (other than the growth in the target)?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate UUIDs. System may sometimes mount one or the other depending which drive BIOS/system brings up to speed first. You must change UUID of one or the other. Best to not use dd for backup. Use rsync or one of the many other tools. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but the `PARTUUID`'s of the partitions are also the same.